# How to get permission in iOS Device at Flutter?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I used the codes in the 'example' field in the application. This 'example', which works perfectly on my Android device, when I press the read button on my iOS device, the application fails and closes the application.

The package that i use:
https://pub.dev/packages/fit_kit

When i click read button i get this error :

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20421af6 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20177e78 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff204219d4 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
    3   HealthKit                           0x00007fff36033520 -[HKHealthStore _validateHealthDataPurposeStringsForSharingTypes:readingTypes:isResearchStudy:] + 931
    4   HealthKit                           0x00007fff36032e98 -[HKHealthStore _validatePurposeStringsForSharingTypes:readingTypes:] + 379
    5   HealthKit                           0x00007fff3603268c -[HKHealthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:readTypes:shouldPrompt:completion:] + 354
    6   HealthKit                           0x00007fff360323f8 -[HKHealthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:readT<…>
Lost connection to device.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Edit info.plist of .xcodeproj: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nshealthshareusagedescription?language=objc

Comment: I already added these settings into my info.plist file but still get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution! I think this is odd. All these bugs, crushes and failures are due to the fact that the permission in "info.plist" named "NSHealthShareUsageDescription" has   tags and I think it doesn't matter if I add any strings to those tags. Unfortunately it was important.. so try those steps to solve:

1. Open "ios/Runner/Info.plist"
2. Check if "NSHealthShareUsageDescription" item is there
3. Add any string message to get permission
4. Save the file and click "Open iOS module in Xcode" at the top.
5. Check if the "Runner / Runner / Info.plist" file in Xcode is the
   same as the "Info.plist" file we have edited.
6. If it's same try to build app.

Hope that works for you!